# I need double quotes around datas from CSV

Tags: python, csv

sorry if this was asked before but I did search for hours and I'm losing my mind, I'm new to Python and I have this CSV file looking like this :

```
A;B C;D;F G;
1;2;3;4
5;6;7;8
```

I need to have them in a variable looking like this :

```
{"A" : 1, "B C": "2", "D":"3","F G":"4"}
{"A" : 5, "B C": "6", "D":"7","F G":"8"}
```

And this is what I do with my python code :

```
import csv

with open('Database.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    firstLine = True
    columnsList = []
    dataList = []
    for row in csv_reader:
        if firstLine:
            columnsList.append(row)
            firstLine = False
        else:
            dataList.append(row)
```

But the datas all always in simple quote, for example my columnList look like this :

```
['A','B C', 'D', 'F G']
```

And I want to it to look like this :

```
["A","B C", "D", "F G"]
```

The data should look like this list too.

Also, I did try :

```
quoting=csv.quote_nonnumeric
```

But it's not working I have an error like "can't convert float to String" if I remember correctly

Any idead pls ? Thank you

Comment: Those quotes *are not actually in your data*, that is simply how the `str` type is choosing to represent the objects in your list.

Comment: Ok thank you ! I'll check it